# Omni completion Does not contain all the php functions

Tags: vim

Omni completion Does not contain all the php functions

Such as

mysqli_query()

what is the solution?

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

First save [funclist.txt](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/phpdoc/doc-base/trunk/funclist.txt?view=co) to somewhere on your machine, mine is at

```
~/.vim/ftplugin/funclist.txt
```

Then, if you don't already have one you must to create an ftplugin for PHP with this content:

```
setlocal dictionary+=~/.vim/ftplugin/funclist.txt
setlocal complete-=k complete+=k
```

I'm sorry but I have no idea where I got this trick from.

Comment: But also do not appear in list functions i am use win7 and put this file in >> C:\Program Files\Vim\vimfiles\ftplugin <<

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Does it work? The name/location of funclist.txt don't really matter. What you have to do is create a file "C:\\path\to\vimruntime\ftplugin\php.vim" containing the two lines above. The first line must be pointing to the actual funclist.txt (wherever it is, however it is named). That's all you need for funclist.txt to be parsed by vim for <C-x><C-o>.