# Autocompletion in Vim

Tags: vim, autocomplete, macvim

I'm having trouble with autocompletion. How can I get a code suggestion while I'm typing?

I usually develop in PHP, Ruby, HTML, C and CSS.

Answer (score 172, accepted):

You can use a plugin like [AutoComplPop](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1879) to get automatic code completion as you type.

2015 Edit: I personally use [YouCompleteMe](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe) now.

Comment: This is highly recommended. Takes the effort out of typing C-X C-O, C-P or C-N.

Comment: I've tried this but it seems doesn't work.. there's probably a conflict with other scripts..

Comment: are you putting the files into the specified directories in ~/.vim?

Comment: @dieguitoweb ACP doesn't work with every filetypes by default. You have to "hack" it to make it work with JavaScript, ActionScript and PHP. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777366/recommended-vim-plugins-for-javascript-coding/4779916#4779916) I explain how I do it. And [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4580695/omni-completion-does-not-contain-all-the-php-functions/4585865#4585865) is another hint for PHP.

Comment: now it works :) all the files were already in the right directories.. I only replaced the script with a new download from the git repository and now it's fine. many thanks

Comment: many thanks, but missing some steps in your instruction.
I have read this: https://bitbucket.org/ns9tks/vim-autocomplpop/issue/22/add-php-support and I fixed the problem with php files

Comment: YCM conflicts with vim-snipmate as of 201708.

Answer (score 539):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>N</kbd> to get a list of word suggestions while in insert mode. Type `:help i_CTRL-N` to see Vim's documentation on this functionality.

[Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20120630181124/http://www.mohdshakir.net/2007/12/27/enable-vim-code-python-auto-complete) is an example of importing the Python dictionary into Vim.

Comment: thanks this is great, but how can I have this list in automatic without pressing <ctrl+N>?

Comment: That's what michaelmichael was telling you with the plugin he mentioned. Also, you might look at SuperTab.

Comment: For CSS support, add the dash for built in autocomplete by adding 'set iskeyword+=-' to your .vimrc

Comment: This is the most comprehensive and native way of doing it :-)

Comment: can I change Ctrl-N to something else, such as ctrl-space?

Comment: Omg, why it is so highly upvoted. The «C-n» is neither semantic, nor even «auto» *(i.e. it isn't autopopups, you have to manually press the combo every time)*.

Comment: @Hi-Angel the 'auto' part is that it automatically determines options for completion of a word, and automatically competes the word upon selection of an option.

Comment: oh wow, years of using vim and never knew that!

Answer (score 73):

If you are using VIM version 8+, just type `Ctrl + n` or `Ctrl + p`.

Comment: Is there a way i could make them pop up without pressing ctrl+p ? i.e i want it to keep suggesting me as along with my typing

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526858/how-do-i-make-vim-do-normal-bash-like-tab-completion-for-file-names

Comment: `ctrl +n/p` will work in earlier versions as well

Answer (score 16):

You can start from built-in `omnifunc` setting.

Just put:

```
filetype plugin on
au FileType php setl ofu=phpcomplete#CompletePHP
au FileType ruby,eruby setl ofu=rubycomplete#Complete
au FileType html,xhtml setl ofu=htmlcomplete#CompleteTags
au FileType c setl ofu=ccomplete#CompleteCpp
au FileType css setl ofu=csscomplete#CompleteCSS
```

on the bottom of your `.vimrc`, then type `<Ctrl-X><Ctrl-O>` in insert mode.

I always rely on this CSS completion.

Comment: what does `setl` mean? Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I got it, it means setlocal. But why do we need setlocal here?

Comment: Take a look at how it annoys you when you open another file in the same buffer.

Comment: @ernix Open another file in the same buffer? Do you mean Vim instance?

Comment: @JakeD No, buffer/window/tab/instance are completely different concepts in Vim.  See also https://sanctum.geek.nz/arabesque/buffers-windows-tabs/ and `:help global-local`

Comment: @ernix From your link: *A buffer in Vim is...an open instance of a file...* I know about buffers, windows, and tabs; but I don't know about opening another file in the same buffer. It seems to me that when you open a file it will always open in a new buffer and add that buffer to the buffer list. I know there are other ways buffers are used, such as the quick fix list, but I didn't know about *changing* what file is in a buffer. `:h buffers` says: *A buffer is a file loaded into memory for editing.* That said, I've only been seriously using Vim for 3 mos. and am certainly open to correction.

Comment: @JakeD Ah yes. You're right.  I took "instance" meaning the wrong way. I misunderstood you were talking about processes with different PIDs.  Sorry, just forget about what I've said.

Answer (score 10):

There is also https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe and it includes things like Jedi and also has fuzzy match. So far I found YCM to be the fastest among what I have tried.

Edit: There also exists some new ones like https://github.com/maralla/completor.vim

Answer (score 7):

Another option is [coc.nvim](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim).

It's really fast and the completion is great as it uses intellisense the same autocompletion as VScode has.
It also has linting capabilities. So it shows you were you might have a bug.
It supports a multitude of languages.

It might take a bit to set up and configure but I think it is the best autocompletion engine for vim out there.

Answer (score 3):

I've used [neocomplcache](https://github.com/Shougo/neocomplcache) for about half a year. It is a plugin that collects a cache of words in all your buffers and then provides them for you to auto-complete with.

There is an array of screenshots on the project page in the previous link. Neocomplcache also has a ton of configuration options, of which there are basic examples on the project page as well.

If you need more depth, you can look at the relevant section in my [vimrc](https://github.com/sp3ctum/Vimrc/blob/master/vimrc) - just search for the word neocomplcache.

Answer (score 1):

Here is [link](http://docs.oseems.com/general/application/vim/auto-complete-php)!  for PHP.

press the Ctrl + x followed by Ctrl + o keys while writing some PHP functions.

Thanks to Oseems Solutions for the tutorial

Answer (score 1):

If you only wanna auto-completion from cache of your current buffers, [supertab](https://github.com/ervandew/supertab) is easier to install than [neocomplete](https://github.com/Shougo/neocomplete.vim), can work on Mac pre-installed vim out of box without the need of MacVim.

You can check other alternatives at [vim awesome](http://vimawesome.com).

Answer (score 0):

For PHP, [Padawan](https://github.com/padawan-php/padawan.php) with [Deoplete](https://github.com/Shougo/deoplete.nvim) are great solutions for having a robust PHP autocompletion in Neovim. I tried a lot of things and Padawan work like a charm!

For Vim you can use [Neocomplete](https://github.com/Shougo/neocomplete.vim) instead of Deoplete.

I wrote an article how to make a [Vim PHP IDE](http://web-techno.net/vim-php-ide/) if somebody is interested. Of course Padawan is part of it.

Answer (score -1):

I recently discovered a project called [OniVim](https://www.onivim.io/), which is an electron-based front-end for NeoVim that comes with very nice autocomplete for several languages out of the box, and since it's basically just a wrapper around NeoVim, you have the full power of vim at your disposal if the GUI doesn't meet your needs. It's still in early development, but it is *rapidly* improving and there is a really active community around it. I have been using vim for over 10 years and started giving Oni a test drive a few weeks ago, and while it does have some bugs here and there it hasn't gotten in my way. I would strongly recommend it to new vim users who are still getting their vim-fingers!

[image]

OniVim: https://www.onivim.io/

Comment: to me the entire point of vim is using the terminal ... if i wanted to use an electron app i'll just use vscode with a vim extension ..

Comment: @MohamedBenkedadra But would that really get you the full power of Vim? I happen to be a huge fan of its search-and-replace pattern system, for one thing, and I'd be pleasantly surprised if a vim-emulation plugin supported that.

Comment: vim does not need GUI, but the electron needs, this is why they cannot be comparable :)

Comment: @SilverWolf but does an electron app gives you the full power of Vim ?
It is not lightweight and thus can not be run through a SSH connection.

Comment: FYI OniVim is [dead](https://github.com/onivim/oni2/issues/3811#issuecomment-910306404)