# map to XF86 keys in vimrc

Tags: vim

I have a chromebook that I've modified to run Arch Linux on.  I have a 'search' key just under the tab key that I'd like to map as autocomplete when in `insert` mode.  `xev` tells me the value of the key is `XF86Search`.  However this doesn't seem to be working:

```
#.vimrc

inoremap <XF86Search> <c-n> mapmode-i$
```

How can I make this mapping with an XF86 key?

**edit**: In fact, using AutoComplPop from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5170109/2128691) proved to be a better solution, but Ingo pointed me in the right direction.  [This question](https://superuser.com/q/198976) on superuser discusses remapping keys for vim and/or terminal using `xmodmap` and that's the way I would have had to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In insert or command-line mode, try typing the search key (maybe preceded by `<C-V>` for literal input). If nothing happens / is inserted, you cannot use that key combination directly in Vim. You would have to remap it outside to some unused key (e.g. `<F13>`) that is supported by Vim. Else, just insert the key literally into your `.vimrc` mapping definition, without the special `<...>` key notation.